# read data xml with xslt into database

Tags: xml, database, xslt

I'm really new to xslt. I have XML in which there are characteristics of a product.
Im my XSLT (based on examples), I have managed to get the characteristics in a table, but I have between 1 and 10 records, based on the number of characteristics.  What I want is instead of X records, I want to have 1 record with X fields. I dont know if this is possible.

Code below is what I'm using now:

```
<xsl:template match="b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics">
        <b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
            <Artikelnummer><xsl:value-of select="../../b:ID"/></Artikelnummer>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
 </xsl:template>
```

Part of the xml:

```
<b:Product>
<b:IndustryAssignedID schemeID="1" schemeAgencyName="VBN">104658</b:IndustryAssignedID>
<b:DescriptionText languageCode="nl">GE MI ALLURE</b:DescriptionText>
<b:TypeCode>57</b:TypeCode>
 <b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:TypeCode listID="8" listAgencyName="VBN">T19</b:TypeCode>
<b:ValueCode listID="9" listAgencyName="VBN">021</b:ValueCode>
</b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:TypeCode listID="8" listAgencyName="VBN">L11</b:TypeCode>
<b:ValueCode listID="9" listAgencyName="VBN">020</b:ValueCode>
</b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:TypeCode listID="8" listAgencyName="VBN">P02</b:TypeCode>
<b:ValueCode listID="9" listAgencyName="VBN">001</b:ValueCode>
</b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:TypeCode listID="8" listAgencyName="VBN">K07</b:TypeCode>
<b:ValueCode listID="9" listAgencyName="VBN">014</b:ValueCode>
</b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:TypeCode listID="8" listAgencyName="VBN">S20</b:TypeCode>
<b:ValueCode listID="9" listAgencyName="VBN">050</b:ValueCode>
</b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:TypeCode listID="8" listAgencyName="VBN">S23</b:TypeCode>
<b:ValueCode listID="9" listAgencyName="VBN">007</b:ValueCode>
</b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:TypeCode listID="8" listAgencyName="VBN">S50</b:TypeCode>
<b:ValueCode listID="9" listAgencyName="VBN">010</b:ValueCode>
</b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:TypeCode listID="8" listAgencyName="VBN">S62</b:TypeCode>
<b:ValueCode listID="9" listAgencyName="VBN">NL</b:ValueCode>
</b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:TypeCode listID="8" listAgencyName="VBN">S97</b:TypeCode>
<b:ValueCode listID="9" listAgencyName="VBN">004</b:ValueCode>
</b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:TypeCode listID="8" listAgencyName="VBN">S98</b:TypeCode>
<b:ValueCode listID="9" listAgencyName="VBN">A1</b:ValueCode>
</b:ApplicableGoodsCharacteristics>
<b:ManufacturerParty    
<c:PrimaryID schemeID="1" schemeAgencyName="FEC">8713782518527</c:PrimaryID>
<c:Name>Holstein Flowers</c:Name>
</b:ManufacturerParty>
</b:Product>
```

Comment: What is your database vendor and version?

Comment: Please show the XML result you expected to get. It would also help to see a [mcve] instead of snippets.

Comment: i tried to copy example of one article but there are to many lines. It is about the upper part. I would like to get the values like: T19, 021, L11,02 etc in one record instead of 10 separate records. because they al belong to one product. And the product whole product schould be presented as 1 line. regards, peter

Comment: any tips for me how to solve this:

it's now in database like:

Artikelnummer TypeCode ValueCode
  5019484919629 L11 010
  5019484919629 S05 099
  5019484919629 S20 045
  5019484919629 S23 010
  5019484919629 S30 021

i would like toe have it in database like:

Artikelnummer TypeCode1 ValueCode1 TypeCode2 ValueCode2 TypeCode3 ValueCode3 TypeCode4 ValueCode4 TypeCode5 ValueCode6
5019484919629 L11 010 S05 099 S20 045 S23 010 S30 021

getting desparate :-(